# Overwrite an image file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, overwrite

Is there a way to overwrite an image already existing in my site using javascript... if yes, what method, and any links for tutorials?

Comment: can you explain what you are attempting to accomplish?

Comment: Do you want to change src of an image? if yes than ```document.getElementById('myImageId').src = 'new-image.png'```

Comment: @Grievoushead there is no suggestion of using jQuery. Good call on posting as a comment because FYI if you post jQuery answers to Javascript questions you often get downvoted.

Comment: Andrew can you clarify whether you want to do this on the web page or the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change the src attribute of your image, you can do something like this:

```js
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myImg").src = 'image2.jpg';
}
</script>
```

```html
<img src="image1.jpg" id="myImg">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Change Image </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a code  example in Js :

```
<script language="javascript">
function ChangeImageSrc(oldSrc, newSrc) {
    var imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++){
        if (imgElements[i].src == oldSrc){
            imgElements[i].src = newSrc;
            break;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with javascript alone - you will need to have something on your server to actually handle the saving of the image. If you want to overwrite an image, you would simply need to provide the same filename when saving and apply the appropriate permissions.

There are lots of resources available for file/image uploads, eg:

https://joelvardy.com/writing/javascript-image-upload
https://css-tricks.com/ajax-image-uploading/

The right solution for you depends on what you have available on your server.

Comment: You can overwrite if the filename is the same without `unlink()`?